# Home Site with menubar, picture and list with tvos - tvml

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

based onto this sample code:
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505
i tried to make a start site like into the app zova
I want to show a menue at the top, which can be shown with a swipe onto the remote control
Each menue point should show directly a subpage.

At the moment it only shows the 3 menue points, but no content into it.
After starting the app, /templates/home/Index.xml will be opened directly. And I only can go back to the menue with the menue button onto the remote controll.

my index xml file has the following content:

```
<document>
<menuBarTemplate>
<menuBar>
  <menuItem id="navigation_top_travel" data-identifier="list" documentURL="/templates/home/Index.xml" autoHighlight="true">
    <title>Home</title>
  </menuItem>
  <menuItem id="navigation_top_remember" data-identifier="remember" documentURL="/templates/remember/Index.xml">
    <title>Likes</title>
  </menuItem>
  <menuItem id="navigation_top_settings" data-identifier="edit" documentURL="/templates/settings/Index.xml">
    <title>Settings</title>
  </menuItem>
</menuBar>
</menuBarTemplate>
</document>
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use getFeature to do this.

```
doc.addEventListener("select", (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const ele = target.parentNode;
    const feature = ele.getFeature("MenuBarDocument");
    const featureDoc = feature.getDocument(target);
    if (featureDoc == null) {
        const documentURL = target.getAttribute("documentURL");
        let docFromURL = your_function_get_doc_from_url(documentURL);
        feature.setDocument(docFromURL);
    }
});
```